How to convert error post mortem output to structured log
We use structured logging in our Rust codebase (e.g. via tracing-subscriber). All is well here.
But if the process crashes/panics, then we see this post mortem as multiple events in our log sink (e.g. DataDog):
index out of bounds: the len is 3 but the index is 99
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:645:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
 ...
   7: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

We are looking for a solution transforming all these post mortem lines to one structured JSON log outside our Rust codebase. In particular not involving panic::set_hook as per answers to Retrieving backtrace from a panic in hook in Rust?
For example, can the post mortem format be configured with the Rust compiler?
Also we already use the vector collector by DataDog.

Can you elaborate why the linked answers for how to do it in panic::set_hook mean you don't want to use panic::set_hook?

Our requirements are (1) the default hook in dev mode (2) custom output for deployed app such that DataDog displays stack traces nicely. Our experience is that's a lot of code in a handler, including serde, after a panic. What if we panic on the way?  Also we do not want to impose setting a hook for every application we deploy, nor can we in some cases.

Your woes about not using panic::set_hook will have to go ignored (if you want to address the output at its source).
If your application is set to "abort" on panics (via cargo profile), then panic::set_hook is the only place for any logic before the process exits.
If your application is set to "unwind" on panics, then you have more options by wrapping code in std::panic::catch_unwind to "handle" the panic yourself (if you want to handle an async task, then there .catch_unwind() from the futures crate via extension trait). You didn't note the nature of your application, so its on you to figure out where that'd need to be but a few ideas:

around each handled "request" on a server
inside each thread spawned

However, you still need a panic::set_hook for two reasons:

if you don't set a custom hook, then you will still get the standard output you get above regardless whether the panic is caught or not.
the only way to acquire a backtrace is at the point of the panic, i.e. in the panic hook. There is a way shown here to smuggle the backtrace out of the panic hook and into your catch logic.

But all things considered, I would recommend not worrying about catching the panic and you should just set a panic hook that prints the minimal JSON you need. Something like this (mimicking the default hook handling):
std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(|info| {
    use std::backtrace::Backtrace;
    use std::io::{stdout, Write};

    let msg = if let Some(s) = info.payload().downcast_ref::<&'static str>() {
        *s
    } else if let Some(s) = info.payload().downcast_ref::<String>() {
        s.as_str()
    } else {
        "Box<dyn Any>"
    };

    let backtrace = Backtrace::force_capture().to_string();

    // ingore any write errors
    let _ = writeln!(stdout(), r#"{{"message":{msg:?},"stack":{backtrace:?}}}"#);
}));

This obviously is manually-crafted JSON but I would likewise not use serde if it can be avoided. You may obviously want more fields like a logging level or Span::current().id() from tracing. Maybe the thread id as well? However, I'm not well-versed in what DataDog (or Vector) wants as the format, so I'll leave the rest to you.

We are async with http server, and sync with cpu-bound tasks, e.g. analytics tools.
